# Json get value from table

Tags: php, json

I have a small code make this result :

> `{"nomdupharmacie":[{"pid":"71","name":"dft","longi":"9.010505676269531","lati":"34.1575970207261","matricule":"M65203124"},{"pid":"72","name":"erezrzer","longi":"7.529407627880573","lati":"34.63767601827405","matricule":"123"},{"pid":"73","name":"qsd","longi":"8.83832462131977","lati":"35.172592315800905","matricule":"333"}],"success":1}`

with this php code :

// get all products from products table

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM nomdupharmacie") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["nomdupharmacie"] = array();
    $v = "12";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["longi"] = $row["longitude"];
        $product["lati"] = $row["latitude"];

        $product["matricule"] = $row["personnel_number"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["nomdupharmacie"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

i have to test for example :
$value = "555"
if $value exists in column of matricule so get alert
so the questionis how to make test if the value exists in the Matricule column or not ??

Comment: `select * from nomdupharmacie where matricule=555`? instead?

Comment: i will try bat 
are there any other solution because I will test if the Matricule is not exist so save data in to database 
if (Service = "555") {
error; 
else {} 
Insert intro .... 
}

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using PDO or ADOdb instead of mysql_query which is deprecated.

The only option is to compare manually like this:

1) create a function that receives an array x and value v to check

```
function isMatriculeInArray($x, $v)
{
    foreach($x as $z)
    {
        if($z["matricule"] == $v)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2) check if matricule is in there

```
if(!isMatriculeInArray($response["nomdupharmacie"], $v)
{
    array_push($response["nomdupharmacie"], $product);
}
```

Comment: it always gives the same result !!